# Why do print and printf show different numbers of decimal places by default

Tags: java

As part of my degree I am required to take a programming course in Java; I am an experienced C# developer, so perhaps what I would expect from C# is conflicting with how Java actually works. The professor of the course couldn't give me a good reason why print and printf produce different results, so I have turned to the internet.

As the title implies, I am getting different output when I use printf and print in a very basic Java application.  The user is prompted for three values: the number of starting organisms (double), the percent change in population (double), and the number of days the population will multiply (int).  I then run a calculation and output the values to the screen like so:

```
    for(int x = 1; x < days; x++)
    {
        startingOrganisms = startingOrganisms + (startingOrganisms * (increasePercent));
        System.out.printf("%d\t\t%f\n", (x + 1), startingOrganisms);    
    }
```

The problem is that this produces different output than if I just do:

```
  System.out.print((x + 1) + "\t\t" + startingOrganisms+ "\n");
```

The image below shows what is produced with the first code sample. My expectation is that both print and printf would yield the same result, but that is not the case. Can anyone explain what the difference is?  Cursory searches of Google didn't turn anything up.

[image]

Comment: See my updated answer for a way to get what you want while still using printf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the fact that by default for `double or float` `printf` print number upto 6 decimal places. You need to specify the precision if you want to control how many decimal places you want to print via `printf`. `System.out.println` prints exact value of double/float without adding some default decimal points.

e.g.

```
    double d = 1.0;
    // it will print 1.000000
    System.out.printf("%f\n", d);
    //1.0
    System.out.printf("%.1f", d);
    //1.0
    System.out.println(d);
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, printf shows 6 decimal digits

You can control the number of decimal digits to show by explicitly specifying the precision. For example, for 12 decimal digits you can do:

```
printf("%.12f", val);
```

API reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#dndec

If you want to get equivalent output to `System.out.println` but for some reason want to keep using printf, then you can do the following:

```
System.out.printf("%d\t\t%f\n", (x + 1), Double.toString(startingOrganisms));
```

Answer (score 0):

print just prints out the message. printf prints out a formatted string so natuaraly you should consider them to use differently

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to double and float ,  printf by default prints up to 6 decimal digits. So in order to amend that result you need to specify how many digits you want to print on your screen.The code above will print up to 10 digits.

for example :

```
 printf("%.10f", val);
```

Comment: Here is the problem with that approach: the tool that grades the output expects a varying degree of precision based on the output. So lines 1,2,and 3 it expects a single degree of precision,  line 4 two degrees, and so on.